# How do I calculate percentages over groups in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in the form:

```
FUND|BROKER|QTY
F1|B1|10
F1|B1|50
F1|B2|20
F1|B3|20
```

When I group it by FUND, and BROKER, I would like to calculate QTY as a percentage of the total at the group level. Like so,

```
FUND|BROKER|QTY %|QTY EXPLANATION
F1|B1|60%|(10+50)/(10+50+20+20)
F1|B2|20%|(20)/(10+50+20+20)
F1|B2|20%|(20)/(10+50+20+20)
```

Or when I group by just FUND, like so

```
FUND|BROKER|QTY %|QTY EXPLANATION
F1|B1|16.66|(10)/(10 + 50)
F1|B1|83.33|(50)/(10 + 50)
F1|B2|100|(20)/(20)
F1|B3|100|(20)/(20)
```

I would like to achieve this using spark-sql if possible or through dataframe functions.

I think I have to use Windowing functions, so I can get access to the total of the grouped dataset, but I've not had much luck using them the right way.

```
Dataset<Row> result = sparkSession.sql("SELECT fund_short_name, broker_short_name,first(quantity)/ sum(quantity) as new_col FROM margin_summary group by fund_short_name, broker_short_name" );
```

Comment: "grouping by" implies using aggregation for each distinct value(s) of grouped column(s). in your charts however, you're not aggregating anything - in the first example your F1 and B2 repeat two times and in the second example your F1 repeats four times. you need to show more consistent examples

Comment: also it seems your examples come in the wrong order: the first one is grouping by fund only (since you sum up all qty for F1 in denominator), the second one is grouping by fund and broker (since you sum up qty for both fund and broker)

Comment: in any case, it's impossible to do with just a single query. you need to do "group by" first (by fund or by fund/broker, whichever applies here) to sum up quantities, and then do inner join (on fund or fund/broker, whichever grouping you used) with the original dataset and while joining, you do the necessary division

Comment: I wrote out the results as you would see on a SQL query ->
   select fund, broker, (whatever) as qty% from tbl group by fund, broker
would create the first dataset.

Comment: yeah it's impossible to get those result rows mentioned above by using that query. they don't match at all. either you should use group by followed by join or you should use more compact query mentioned in the answer below (which is basically the same thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You are right when you say that you need to use windowed analytical functions.
Please find below the solutions to your queries.

Hope it helps!

```
spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").csv("****").withColumn("fundTotal",sum("QTY").over(Window.partitionBy("FUND"))).withColumn("QTY%",sum("QTY").over(Window.partitionBy("BROKER"))).select('FUND,'BROKER,(($"QTY%"*100)/'fundTotal).as("QTY%")).distinct.show
```

And the second!

```
spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").csv("/vihit/data.csv").withColumn("QTY%",sum("QTY").over(Window.partitionBy("BROKER"))).select('FUND,'BROKER,(('QTY*100)/$"QTY%").as("QTY%")).distinct.show
```

Answer (score 1):

PySpark SQL solution.

This can be done using `sum` as a window function defining 2 windows - one with a grouping on broker, fund and the other only on fund.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum
w1 = Window.partitionBy(df.fund,df.broker)
w2 = Window.partitionBy(df.fund)
res = df.withColumn('qty_pct',sum(df.qty).over(w1)/sum(df.qty).over(w2))
res.select(res.fund,res.broker,res.qty_pct).distinct().show()
```

Edit: Result 2 is simpler.

```
res2 = df.withColumn('qty_pct',df.qty/sum(df.qty).over(w1))
res2.show()
```

SQL solution would be

```
select distinct fund,broker,100*sum(qty) over(partition by fund,broker)/sum(qty) over(partition by fund)
from tbl
```

Comment: that covers his first example only, would be better to add the solution for the second example as well, for completeness